# Searching for the frequency of a word in a string (C++)

Tags: c++, word-frequency

I have to write a program that asks the user for a sentence (with a limit of 1024 letters), then asks the user for a word, and tells the user how many times that specific word occurs in the sentence, for an assignment.

We're only allowed to use these libraries: iostream, string, cstring, cstdlib, cmath and fstream.

example of how it's supposed to function:

Enter a sentence:

input:hello my name is hello hello

Enter a word to check for frequency:

input:hello

desired output:# of times word occurs: 3

actual output:# of times word occurs: 25

This is what I tried using with the help of a friend, but when I enter a word to search it outputs an unrelated number.

```
int wordFrequency(){
    char sen5[1024];
    int frequency = 0;
    char word[1024];
    cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
    cin.getline(sen5, 1024);
    cout << "Enter a word to check for frequency: " << endl;
    cin.getline(word, 1024);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(sen5); i++){
            if(sen5[i] == word[i]){
                    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
                            if(sen5[j] == word[j])
                                    frequency += 1;
            }
    }
    cout << "# of times word occurs: " << frequency << endl;
    return 0;
```

}

Also, I'm aware my coding is horrid, my professor is notoriously horrible and I'm struggling immensely in my class because of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the exact input you're using the exact output you're receiving.

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but it's for your own good. Learn to use your debugger. Which debugger do you have access to? If you don't know, which IDE/OS are you using?

Comment: Observe the simple fact that `frequency += 1` gets executed for every matching letter. Therefore, if the sentence was only "banana", and the word to search for was "banana", the shown code will arrive at the conclusion that this word was found six times. Given that, and the fact that if the word to search gets specified as "an", instead, this same algorithm (ignoring the defective counting, for the moment) will find it three times in "banana", I'm afraid that your approach is fundamentally flawed, and you need to start from scratch, and think a little bit harder of what needs to happen here.

Comment: Perhaps "an unrelated number" is not as accurate as "I don't see how this number relates"? Withholding key information (input, expected output, and actual output) only hurts your chances of getting help.

Comment: I may have made a poor word choice in my previous comment. I did not intent to imply intentional withholding, just that the opportunity to supply the information was there and not taken advantage of. Sorry if there was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So friend if you are only allowed to use `isostream,, string, cstring, cstdlib, cmath and fstream.` then you can program it in C++ language.

So below code only uses `iostream` for input/output operations.
you can also use string.h to find the string length but i have gone the other way.

for finding the occurrence's of a word below is the function:

```
int countOccurrences(char * str, char * toSearch)
{
    int i, j, found, count;
    int stringLen, searchLen;

    int cou = 0;
    while(str[cou] != '\0'){
        cou++;
    }
    stringLen = cou; 
    cou = 0;  
    while(toSearch[cou] != '\0'){
        cou++;
    }
    searchLen = cou; 

    count = 0;

    for(i=0; i <= stringLen-searchLen; i++)
    {

        found = 1;
        for(j=0; j<searchLen; j++)
        {
            if(str[i + j] != toSearch[j])
            {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

And for taking the input you can write the things in main function and then call the above function in main. Below is the code for that:

```
int main()
{
    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    char toSearch[MAX_SIZE];
    int count;

    cout<<"Enter any string: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
    cout<<"Enter word to search occurrences: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(toSearch, sizeof(toSearch));
    count = countOccurrences(str, toSearch);
    cout<<"Total occurrences of"<< toSearch<<" : "<< count;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems you are beginner in the coding stuff so for more:
below is the code you need to add at the starting of your code. Header file and declaring the countOccurences function.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
using namespace std;

int countOccurrences(char * str, char * toSearch);
```

So this way you can count the number of occurrences/frequency of a word in a string with using `iostream` header only.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you, but the libraries I provided are the only ones we're allowed to use, not the ones we're not allowed to use.

Comment: Ok. Ill edit the answer in a moment

Comment: Check now brother. Program is using only iostream header only. Is that fine